# Symbolic integration conditional bug?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I just ran across this:

```
Assuming[x > 0, Integrate[1/t^2, {t, 1, x}]]
```

gives the output

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[(-1 + x)/x, x > 1]
> ```

which is clearly too restricted. The correct conditional should be `x>0`.

The result doesn't evaluate at `x=1/2`, but

```
Integrate[ 1/t^2, {t, 1, 1/2} ]
```

correctly evaluates to `-1`.

Any thoughts for a workaround?

---

I'm on *OSX* with *Mathematica 9.0.1.0*.

EDIT:

The result cannot be explained by Mathematica having a strong requirement of the upper boundary being strictly greater than the lower boundary of the integral. This can be seen when integrating over functions without singularity or by moving the singularity but not the lower boundary. In this case the conditional is also shifted, despite the unchanged lower boundary.

So there must be some (unintented) interaction between mixed constant and variable boundaries and singularities.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: `GenerateConditions -> False`?

Comment: Well, yes, but I'd actually appreciate having correct conditionals :). Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: but when writing `Assuming[x > 0, Integrate[1/t^2, {t, 1, x}]]`, then  in here `1` is min, and x is max. According to help. Hence x has to be greater than 1. In the second example, when you wrote `Integrate[ 1/t^2, {t, 1, 1/2} ]` here you are giving numerical values for the limits, so it knows that the upper limit is less than the lower limit?

Comment: I wasn't sure what sort of workaround you sought, an expression that would evaluate or a precise, correct result.

Comment: Honestly? They enforce such an arbitrary order constraint on integral boundaries?

Comment: see help on Integrate., it says `Integrate[f,{x,Subscript[x, min],Subscript[x, max]}]`

Comment: @Nasser, I see that, but it says nowhere that x_min<x_max must actually be true. It just refers to them as the integral boundaries for the definite integral.

Comment: Also, evaluating Assuming[ x>0, Integrate[ 1/(t-1/2)^2, {t,1,x} ] ] shows that this is not the case, as the result is given for x<1 too. The problem rather seems to be the location of the singularity with respect to the lower boundary argument.

Comment: If the limit is symbol, there has to be a convention. THis is what we do on paper. How would you integrate $\int_{0}^x \,dt$ ? Will the answer be $x-0$ or $0-x$ ? any way, that what I think.

Comment: It also works correctly for any other integral that does not have a singularity. Integrate[ t, {t,0,x} ] works just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to imply with your example. $\int_0^x dt$ is clearly $x$ and not $-x$.

Comment: I was going to suggest `Integrate[t, {t, 1, x}]` as a workaround, but I see you've considered it.  Its output suggests that *M* thinks there's a problem at `t` or `x` equal to `1`.  It might be a bug.  There is someone on the site who might actually know what's going on and be able to comment.

Answer (score 3):

community wiki, not an answer, just some hints, too small for comment:

```
Integrate[1/t^2, {t, 1, x}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

May be some smart math person can decode the above. Now:

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals], Integrate[1/t^2, {t, 1, x}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the `x>1` condition comes out just from say `x` is real. fyi, This is how Maple does it:

```
int(1/t^2, t=1..x) ;
```

It does not even integrate this, it says:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However,

```
 int(1/t^2, t=1..x) assuming x>0 ;
```

gives same as Mathematica:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But Maple does not generate answers with conditionals like Mathematica. User must give the conditions. So the above is for `x>0`.   But using `AllSolutions` will make it generate this

```
 int(1/t^2, t=1..x,AllSolutions )  ;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above seems to be the answer the OP is expecting to get from Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

First, `Integrate` normally takes the assumptions as given and only adds conditions that are needed beyond the assumptions specified.  Thus I would expected the integral

```
Assuming[x > 0, Integrate[1/t^2, {t, 1, x}]]
```

to result in

```
1 - 1/x
```

instead of a `ConditionalExpression`, since the assumption `x > 0` is sufficient to guarantee the result is valid.

The integral by itself produces a (somewhat) correct result:

```
int = Integrate[1/t^2, {t, 1, x}]
(*
ConditionalExpression[
 1 - 1/x, ((Re[1/(-1 + x)] >= 0 || 
      Re[1/(-1 + x)] <= -1) && (x ∉ Reals || 
      Re[1/(-1 + x)] < -1 || Re[x] >= 1)) || 
  1/(-1 + x) ∉ Reals]
*)
```

It evaluates correctly but in two cases produces messages at `x -> 0` and `x -> 1`:

```
Table[int, {x, {-1, 1/2, 2}}]
(*
  {Undefined, -1, 1/2}
*)

int /. x -> 0
(* Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >> *)
(*
  Undefined
*)

int /. x -> 1
(* Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >> (several) *)
(*
  0
*)
```

But there's something funny going at with `x -> 1`.  The condition `1/(-1 + x) ∉ Reals` evaluates to `True` for `x -> 1`, and therefore the integral expression is valid.  But some functions take the expression `1/(-1 + x)` in the condition to impose a restriction on `x`, that `x ≠ 1`.  For instance

```
MapAt[
 Reduce[# && x > 0] &,
 Integrate[1/t^2, {t, 1, x}],
 2]
(*
  ConditionalExpression[1 - 1/x, 0 < x < 1 || x > 1]
*)
```

This may have something to do with the result of the OP's integral.

Finally, another way to get a correct result is to give the integral a good whack and knock 
it off the real line:

```
Assuming[x > 0, Integrate[1/t^2, {t, 1, I, x}]]
(*
  1 - 1/x
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this just as a comment. It seems you should explicitly say to integrate that you want work with 'say' inversed boundaries, because only then it understands it:

```
Integrate[1/t^2, {t, 1, x}, Assumptions -> x < 1]
```

> ConditionalExpression[(-1 + x)/x, x > 0]

I suppose it rather some kind of reticence. As a workaround I could suggest one can work this way:

```
x1 = 1;
xlowlimit = 0;

fun[t_] := -1/t^2;

If[x1 < xlowlimit ,
  Assuming[x > x1reg, Integrate[fun[t], {t, x1, x}]],
 {ConditionalExpression[
    Assuming[xlowlimit < x < x1, Integrate[fun[t], {t, x1, x}]], x1reg < x < x1],
  Assuming[xlowlimit < x, Integrate[fun[t], {t, x1, x}]]}]
```